# Why is XML element invalid?

Tags: xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<accounts>
    <1167/>
    <1328/>
    <1505/>
    <1536 default="true" />
    <1966/>
</accounts>
```

When I pass in the above XML at http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_validator.asp I get an error stating the line with <1167/> is invalid. I looked at the w3 description for elements, and didn't see any reason why it should be wrong. I'm sure its a simple mistake so would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taken from http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp

> **XML Naming Rules**
>
> XML elements must follow these naming rules:
>
> Names cannot start with a number or punctuation character

or (more authoritative) http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/

> Name start characters must have one of the categories Ll, Lu, Lo, Lt, Nl.

Where the categories starting with `L` are various classes of "letters" in Unicode and `Nl` are numbers that looks like a letter, such as a Roman numerals (Ⅰ, Ⅱ, Ⅲ, Ⅳ, Ⅴ...).

Answer (score 9):

The name of an element must [not start with a digit](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameStartChar)¹.

Also, the name of an element should describe the "class" or "type" of the represented entity, and be static. Might I suggest:

```
<accounts>
    <account number="1167"/>
    <account number="1328"/>
    <account number="1505"/>
    <account number="1536" default="true" />
    <account number="1966"/>
</accounts>
```

¹ <sub>For some reason, many answers here link to w3schools (which is *not* affiliated with the W3C). Instead, you should only trust the [XML standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/).</sub>

Comment: +1 for not promoting w3schools with one new link to their website! link http://www.w3fools.com instead :).

Answer (score 2):

Because it starts with a number and that is not allowed. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp).

> **XML Naming Rules**
>
> XML elements must follow these naming rules:
>
> - Names can contain letters, numbers, and other characters
> - Names cannot start with a number or punctuation character
> - Names cannot start with the letters xml (or XML, or Xml, etc)
> - Names cannot contain spaces
> - Any name can be used, no words are reserved.

Answer (score 1):

XML element names cannot start with a number. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp), for example.